# put legend of area chart inside the figure

Tags: r, ggplot2

here is my data and my area chart:

```
df<- data.frame(age=15:40,h1= 25:50,h2=35:60,h3=45:70)
data1<- df %>% gather(timeuse, minute, -age)

ggplot(data1, aes(x = age, y = minute, fill = timeuse)) +
  geom_area() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Gray")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(15, 90, by = 5))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1500, by = 100))+
  theme_classic()
```

I want to put legend inside the area chart like this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general that could be easily achieved using `geom_text` with `position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)`. Depending on your real data the tricky part would be to select the `x` positions where you want to place the labels. In my code below I use `dplyr::case_when` to set different positions for each category of `timeuse`. Additionally depending on your real data it might be worthwhile to have a look at `ggrepel::geom_text_repel`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data1 <- data1 %>% 
  mutate(label = case_when(
    timeuse == "h3" & age == 20 ~ timeuse,
    timeuse == "h2" & age == 27 ~ timeuse,
    timeuse == "h1" & age == 35 ~ timeuse,
    TRUE ~ ""
  ))

p <- ggplot(data1, aes(x = age, y = minute, fill = timeuse)) +
  geom_area() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(15, 90, by = 5))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1500, by = 100))+
  theme_classic()

p + 
  geom_text(aes(label = label), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to have different position? as my picture.

Comment: Try this https://allancameron.github.io/geomtextpath/

Comment: @mehmo I just made an edit to place the labels at different positions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually with annotate

```
annotate("text", x=50, y=2, label= "market work")
```

or more automated, something like this (play with the selection of rows where you want to place them):

```
  geom_text(data = df%>% group_by(timeuse) %>% sample_n(1),
            aes(x = Age, y = minute, 
                label = rev(timeuse), color = rev(timeuse)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```